# How to shorten this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, mouseenter

I'm trying to create `on()` `mouseenter` function for each element, but is there any way to shorten that function somehow. The problem is that I've created that on `mouseenter` function several times. Please help guys :)

This is the code below

```js
var $member1 = $('.team-content img:nth-child(1)'),
  $member2 = $('.team-content img:nth-child(2)'),
  $member3 = $('.team-content img:nth-child(3)'),
  $member4 = $('.team-content img:nth-child(4)')

$(".member1").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $member1.css({
    "left": "0px"
  });
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $member1.css({
    "left": ""
  });
});

$(".member2").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $member2.css({
    "left": "0px"
  });
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $member2.css({
    "left": ""
  });
});

$(".member3").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $member3.css({
    "left": "0px"
  });
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $member3.css({
    "left": ""
  });
});

$(".member4").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $member4.css({
    "left": "0px"
  });
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $member4.css({
    "left": ""
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="team" class="about-team">
  <div class="team-header">
    <h2 class="team-text">Our Team</h2>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-content">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member1">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">John Doe</h2>
        <span>/CEO</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member2">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">Jesica Ice</h2>
        <span>/DESIGNER</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member4">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">Anna Moon</h2>
        <span>/MARKETER</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member3">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">Michael Huge</h2>
        <span>/DEVELOPER</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main-team" class="team-content">

  <img src="assets/img/team/team1.jpeg" alt="Team 1">
  <img src="assets/img/team/team2.jpg" alt="Team 2">
  <img src="assets/img/team/team3.jpg" alt="Team 3">
  <img src="assets/img/team/team4.jpg" alt="Team 4">

</div>
```

Comment: Use commas to add multiple selectors so you only have on function. IE  ".member1, .member2, .member3" etc.

Comment: If this code works and is your own, you might be able to ask this question on [codereview.se], but check their help center before posting.

Comment: Might want to show the HTML on which this code runs; it would clear up some assumptions people are making regarding your variable and class names.

Comment: If you had some way to correlate the `memberN` class to the `nth-child` (could just use a simple substr of the class, but not 100% sure that is always true, you could just use that to generate the selector for the `$memberN` variable and then use the same callback for each element.

Comment: that with commas, i have tried it but when i hover on 1 element other ones are hovered as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have over-thought it, but if the member number and the nth-child number are the same, why not use that to create the relevant accessor? I've got three functions here: the first runs on initialization and saves the integer portion of the member number as a data attribute for later retrieval. The mouseenter and mouseleave functions retrieve that saved member number, and build the selector using that.

```js
$("div[class*='member']").each(function() {
    // for every member element, let's save its
    //  relevant nth-child number.
    var myNumber = 0;
    var myClasses = $(this).prop("class").split(" ");
   
  // check all classes to find the member number
    for (var i = 0; i <= myClasses.length; i++) {
      if ( myClasses[i].startsWith("member") ) {
        // strip out JUST the number portion.
        myNumber = myClasses[i].match(/\d+/)[0];
      }
      if( myNumber != 0 )
      break;
    }
    // Save the number portion for later.
    $(this).data("nthNumber", myNumber);
  }).on('mouseenter', function() {
    // retrieve the saved number
    var selector = ".team-content img:nth-child("+ $(this).data("nthNumber") +" )"; 
    $(selector).show();
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    // retrieve the saved number
    var selector = ".team-content img:nth-child("+ $(this).data("nthNumber") +" )"; 
    $(selector).hide();
  });
```

```css
.about-team {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
.team-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
.team-content img {
  display: none;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="team" class="about-team">
  <div class="team-header">
    <h2 class="team-text">Our Team</h2>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-content">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member1">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">John Doe</h2>
        <span>/CEO</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member2">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">Jesica Ice</h2>
        <span>/DESIGNER</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member4">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">Anna Moon</h2>
        <span>/MARKETER</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member3">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">Michael Huge</h2>
        <span>/DEVELOPER</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main-team" class="team-content">

  <img src="assets/img/team/team1.jpeg" alt="Team 1">
  <img src="assets/img/team/team2.jpg" alt="Team 2">
  <img src="assets/img/team/team3.jpg" alt="Team 3">
  <img src="assets/img/team/team4.jpg" alt="Team 4">

</div>
```

So a few changes made: first, I'd left the initial selector wrong. Then, I added some CSS styles so we could see something happening. The advantage of this approach (while it may be longer) is that it's extensible. If you add thirty more employees, you'd have to create a variable for each one, and use that each time. By this approach, it's happening automatically.

Comment: nope not working, ahaha and yeah you definitely over-thought it :DDD

Comment: Heh. Hoped you'd like that.

Comment: As I note, it is longer, but it becomes a black-box solution. It doesn't matter how many member* elements I have, I simply run over all of them, add that data-attribute, and bind its events. Best of luck, Haji.

Comment: Thank you @Snowmonkey :)))))

Comment: @HAJIHASHIMOV I've added a simpler solution, you can take a look on it if you like :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a general handler and apply the function on the corresponding `.member*` element if you detect the index of the hovered `img` using the [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function, Here is an example: (In the example I change the color just for clarity)

```js
$(".team-content img").on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  var imageIndex = $(".team-content img").index(e.target) + 1;
  $(".member" + imageIndex).css({
    "color": "red"
  });
}).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  var imageIndex = $(".team-content img").index(e.target) + 1;
  $(".member" + imageIndex).css({
    "color": "black"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="team" class="about-team">
  <div class="team-header">
    <h2 class="team-text">Our Team</h2>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-content">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member1">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">John Doe</h2>
        <span>/CEO</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member2">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">Jesica Ice</h2>
        <span>/DESIGNER</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member4">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">Anna Moon</h2>
        <span>/MARKETER</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 member3">
        <h2 class="t-seperator">Michael Huge</h2>
        <span>/DEVELOPER</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main-team" class="team-content">
  <img src="assets/img/team/team1.jpeg" alt="Team 1">
  <img src="assets/img/team/team2.jpg" alt="Team 2">
  <img src="assets/img/team/team3.jpg" alt="Team 3">
  <img src="assets/img/team/team4.jpg" alt="Team 4">
</div>
```

Comment: ? How do you know `".member1"` relates in any way to `".team-content img"`?

Comment: `var $member1 = $('.team-content img:nth-child(1)'),` @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: ... and that's `$member1`, not `.member1`. There's a difference between variable names and class names...

Comment: yes but i want to use one function for each element on hovered seperately? is this the solution here you pointed.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan What the asker is trying to achieve is a general code that is not to be repeated for each `img`, what this code does is add an event handler for all `img`s once, and the code will know which `img` to handle using the `e.target` property which hold the `HTML` element that triggered the event.

Comment: I think you guys are missing, as @MikeMcCaughan said, that `$member1` and some on are variables...while `.member1` is a css class. They aren't interchangable

Comment: That's not what the code provided says though. You're assuming that the element returned by the query `$(".member1")` is the same as the one returned by `$('.team-content img:nth-child(1)')`. You may be correct in your assumption, but there's no evidence that it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a loop to get them all done at once!

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $('.member' + i).on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('.team-content img:nth-child(' + i + ')').css({'left': '0px'});
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.team-content img:nth-child(' + i + ')').css({'left': ''});
    });
}
```

Comment: when i hover on element member1 for example... img is not appearing.